# Implicit convertion within a sequence

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a sequence of instances where each instance can be implicitly converted to the same type. 
What is the best way to convert such sequence?

```
  class A
  class B

  trait Resolver {
    def resolve: String
  }

  implicit class AResolver(a: A) extends Resolver {
    def resolve: String = "a"
  }
  implicit class BResolver(b: B) extends Resolver {
    def resolve: String = "b"
  }

  def resolveThem(a: Option[A], b: Option[B]): Iterable[String] = {
    val resolvers: Seq[Resolver] = a ++ b // type error
    val resolvers: Seq[Resolver] = List(a, b).collect{case Some(x: Resolver) => x} // empty
    val resolvers: Seq[Resolver] = List(a, b).collect{case Some(x: A) => x} // unexpectedly for me but it is also type error when there is an x:A
    val resolvers: Seq[Resolver] = List(a, b).collect{case Some(x: A) => x:Resolver} // works but returns only A as resolver
    val resolvers: Seq[Resolver] = List(a, b).collect{case Some(x /*something that can be implicitly converted to Resolver*/) => x:Resolver} // Is it possible?
    val resolvers: Seq[Resolver] = List(a.get, b.get) // this bad approach works
    resolvers.map(_.resolve) // this is what I want as result
    a.map(_.resolve) ++ b.map(_.resolve) // there is another way but if I have more arguments it becomes too long
  }
```

Comment: It seems a wrong usage of implicit class for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can only use implicits when exact type is available to compiler. As soon as you put your objects into a simple `List` their individual types disappear. (You could use `HList` though.)
2. For two arguments you just use your working approach.
3. For more arguments you might want to have a builder with one argument.

   ```
   trait Builder {
     def add[A: Resolver](a: A): Builder = {
       use(a.resolve)
       this
     }
   }
   ```
4. If there are only a few classes, you could use runtime match:

   ```
   def getResolver(any: Any): Resolver = any match {
     case a: A => a: Resolver
     case b: B => b: Resolver
     case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$any is not supported"
   }
   ```

   However, this approach is very very bad. It is not extensible.
5. You could also use type classes instead of implicit conversions.

   ```
     trait Resolvable[T] {
       def resolve(a: T): String
     }
     implicit class AResolvable extends Resolvable[A] {
       def resolve(a: A): String = "a"
     }
   ```

   This is the preferred way, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Method `collect` accepts `PartialFunction[A, B]`, which means that function is defined only on a subset of the possible input arguments `A` and implicit conversions would not be applied.

Conversion should be done either explicitly or beforehand. One way of doing this for your case is a method taking varargs or a sequence:

```
def resolveThem (resolvers: Option[Resolver]*): Iterable[String] = {
  resolvers.flatten.map(_.resolve)
}

resolveThem(Option(new A), Option(new B))
```